# Construct a correlation matrix using the covariance method

Tags: autocorrelation

I want to compute the autocorrelation matrix by using the covarience method.

X(n) is the harmonic process $X(n) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^3  A_i e^{jn\omega_i} + V(n)$

$V(n)$ is unit variance noise.

$ |A_i| = 2$ for $n = 1,2,3$

The phases of $A_i$ are uncorrelated random variables that are uniformly distributed between $–π$ and $π$.

what I understand:

- $R_{x(n)} = E[x_{n}\cdot x_{n}^H]$
- I should use a levinson or schur algorithm
- I need to compute random samples of the random process ( $randn(100,1$) )
- I should use a for loop to compute the sum

What I don't understand:

- why is the auto correlation matrix a 7 x 7 matrix?
- how do I compute the auto correlation matrix

Comment: Why do you assume that the auto correlation matrix a 7 x 7 matrix?